# I can't find any swagger configuration file in api platform

Tags: symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I'm using the last version of Api-platform, shipped with swagger.io .

I'm having an issue with swagger interface. When I try to use it to Get a resource, it doesn't seem to be able to find any base url or server url.

Logically, I tried to find if I could tell Swagger where to fetch my resources.

I tried to tell swagger what the base path or the url of my server is but I can't find any swagger configuration file.

**My question is : is there any swagger configuration file in api_platform files ? Is there any way to create one where I could tell swagger where to look for my resources and what server to fetch them from.**

By the way, swagger shows me no 'base url' header below the title of my API.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Visit http://yourproject/docs for public endpoints. Visit https://api-platform.com/ for the getting started guide.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What **exactly** happens? Is there any precise error message?

Comment: Also, please share the exact versions you are using

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I tried to add screens and informations in my answer

Answer (score 0):

API Platform create OpenAPI specification [automatically](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/) based on your resources configuration.

You can use `@ApiProperty.attributes.openapi_context` annotation or `api_platform.swagger.normalizer.documentation` decorator for customization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it already. What I decorate shows up in the /docs.json file, but doesn't solve my problem.